# Seaching payments does not filter by date

Tags: php, json, api, curl, mercadopago

I'm trying to search and filter some of my recieved mercadopago payments via it's API. I'm making a Curl request using PHP7. One of my filters is a range date (begin_date, end_date), but that filter is not working propertly!. Here is my code, thanks in advance!

```
    $begin = '2018-08-01';
    $end = '2018-09-01';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/search?collector.id=me&'.
            'access_token='.'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'.'&'.
            'begin_date='.$begin.'&'.
            'end_date='.$end.'&'.
            'status=approved'.'&'.
            'offset=0'.'&'.
            'limit=1000'
    ));
    $payments = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

I made a try using a rest console but the output was the same! an out-of-range list of payments, starting in the begining of times and finishing on the limit (1000).

The API response is:

```
{
"paging": {
    "total": 2739,
    "limit": 2,
    "offset": 0
},
"results": [
    {
        "id": SOME_INT,
        "date_created": "2018-03-01T19:25:24.000-04:00",
        "date_approved": "2018-03-01T19:25:26.000-04:00",
        "date_last_updated": "2018-03-20T13:18:43.000-04:00",
        "money_release_date": "2018-03-03T19:25:26.000-04:00",
        "..." : "...",
        .
        .
        .

    },
    {
        ...
    },
  ]
}
```

Also I tried using the "friendly" date range given by documentation:

```
$begin = "NOW-1MONTH";
$end = "NOW";
```

Comment: What does enabling error reporting reveal and what does `var_dump($payments);` and/or echoing show?

Comment: It returns a JSON with the correct format but out of the date range

Comment: so this is JSON-related. You should add the tag for it and the relevant code for it, should there be relevance. This, including the output you're getting.

Comment: You have an answer now, see how that works out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/api-docs/account/payments/search/)  the format is `2018-08-01T00:00:00Z`

```
curl -G -X GET \ -H "accept: application/json" \
"https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/search" \
-d "access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d "payment_type_id=credit_card" \
-d "operation_type=regular_payment" \
-d "range=date_created" \
-d "begin_date=2014-10-21T00:00:00Z" \
-d "end_date=2014-10-25T24:00:00Z"
```

Note that this code is copied directly from the documentation

Comment: Using the documentation date format is not working either

Comment: Check the "Search Examples" in the documentation. Try specifying things like `"range=date_created" `  to see if that works for you

Comment: Worked like a charm! haha. Thanks I saw it but I did not think it was necessary.

Comment: @QSoto Glad to hear!